# Como proceder ao ter que aplicar um hotfix emergencial?

Tags: git

Se eu estiver trabalhando em um branch referente a uma nova funcionalidade e precisar sair para criar um hotfix. Como proceder? Devo aplicar um commit “temporário” no branch atual ou teria outra abordagem?

Comment: Às vezes eu aplico no branch corrente e pego por cherry-pick no master

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o comando [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Fazendo-Stash)

Ele serve exatamente para guardar o que você estava fazendo, permitindo que você possa fazer um hotfix e depois você retoma digitando:

`git stash apply`

Você pode inclusive criar mais de um stash e pode conferir os existentes digitando:

`git stash list`